# How to reset height: calc()

Tags: css, height, calc

I have a problem with a div that is set to:
    height: calc(100% - 100px);

This is working just fine on a normal screen. But as I change the size of the viewport to < 1000px, I want the height to be just 100%. But setting:
    height: 100%;

doesn't seem to reset the calc() completely.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You need to show your the code if you want people to understand fully your problem

Answer (score 2):

Can you show your code?

With @media query you can do this

Try this:

```css
#menu { 
    background-color: rgba(44,47,49,1.0); 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    width: 320px; 
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0); 
    height: calc(100% - 245px); 
    padding: 30px; 
    margin-top: 115px; 
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    #menu { 
        height: 100%; 
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
</div>
```

Comment: See the code above, in #menu put height with calc and in media put height 100%. I think you don't need screen on media

Answer (score 0):

this is the css for the normal menu div:

`#menu {
    background-color: rgba(44,47,49,1.0);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 320px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    height: calc(100% - 245px);
    height: -o-calc(100% - 245px); /* opera 
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 245px); /* google, safari 
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 245px); /* firefox */
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 115px;
    z-index: 99999 !important;}`

And then for smaller devices (now I set the height to 80px instead of 100%:

`@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #menu {
    padding: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: inherit;}
}`

and the html:

`<div id="menu">
        <div class="title">Menu</div>
        <ul>
        <li class="button code"><a href="#">Code</a></li>
        <li class="button camera"><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
        <li class="button people"><a href="#">Participants</a></li>
        <li class="button more">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-more">
            <label for="toggle-more">More</label>
                <div class="sub">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="button bars"><a href="#">Leaderboard</a></li>
                        <li class="button chat"><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="button close selected hidden">Close</li>
        <ul>
    </div>`

Do you need something more?

Comment: Welcome on SO :) There has never been the need for the `-o-` prefix with `calc()` property according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc). Apart from MAYBE webkit (Saf 6.x), you can ditch all prefixes or use Autoprefixer (to be configured with the exact list of browsers you need to support) and never have to think about these prefixes ever.